# Range of function $f$ taking integer $n$ to a coset of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

I am trying to find the name of the range of a function $f$ which takes an integer $n$ to a coset of $\mathbb{Z}/ n \mathbb{Z}$. Note that to each different integer, the coset belongs to a different group, e.g., $f(2)= c_2+ \mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}$ while $f(3)=c_3+ \mathbb{Z}/3 \mathbb{Z}$.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm afraid this does not have a specific name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The range would just be a subset of $\bigcup_{n\in \Bbb N}\{z + n\Bbb Z \mid z\in \Bbb Z\}$, where we are sure to think of the union as a disjoint union of these sets of cosets.

I've never seen a special name for this set or such a function into this set.

I am sorely tempted to call it a "coset bundle", but apparently that name actually has a use already!

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with infinite products? I don't know if there's a specific name for the range of a function like this, but they are exactly the elements  of the generalized product $\prod_{n \in \Bbb Z} \Bbb Z / n \Bbb Z$, and once you assume $f(n) \in \Bbb Z/n \Bbb Z$, you can identify the functions with its range.